# Dynamically creating SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, console, element

Here is a jsfiddle examples I am playing with:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vz383zh/

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var newRect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"rect");
      newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"width",Math.random() * 100); 
      newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"height",Math.random() * 100);        
      newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"x",Math.random() * 250);     
      newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"y",Math.random() * 180 + 60);    
      newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"fill-opacity",Math.random());        
      var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      newRect.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
      document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].appendChild(newRect);
```

However, I am unable to create SVG elements with writing the following code in the console:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var newRec = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"rect");
newRec.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","black");
newRec.setAttributeNS (null, "width", "100");
newRec.setAttributeNS (null, "height", "50");
newRec.setAttributeNS (null, "x", "50");
newRec.setAttributeNS (null, "y", "50");
var prevRec = document.getElementsByTagName ("rect")[0];
var parent = prevRec.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore (newRec, prevRec);
```

Comment: You seem to have a syntax here: "prevRecG", shouldn't it be "prevRec"?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Nikolay, that is a mistake (correctly), however, for some reason, browser doesnt render SVG elements on screen...

Comment: I've tried it here, seems to work fine (Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/xoLrr2et/. Which browser do you use? Old IE may have an issue with .insertBefore and SVG.

Comment: @Nikolay I actually am using Firefox Firebug and typing the commands in the console... It appears in DOM but not rendering for some reason...

Comment: That's odd. Have just tried that - seems to work fine from FF console as well.

Comment: @Nikolay it does appear in DOM, however, the SVG element is not visible on the screen, is that the same case for you?